# How does gradle lint errors depend on the minSdkVersion?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, lint

I'm currently developing on an app using:

```gradle
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 19    // to be 16 
        targetSdkVersion 19 // to be 25 
        ...
    }
}
```

As you can see my min/max APIs are both 19, but my intention is to build for 16 to 25. (The app has already been developed and used in this range.) At API 19, I get ~200 lint warnings/errors, some for various forms of deprecation. So my question is:

**Would fixing all lint errors under API 19 cause app incompatibility problems when changing the API to range from 16 to 25?**

PS. No I can't test because I simply have no access to devices of earlier/later AOS's. Or did I miss something?